# Accessing Hive through web browser using thrift php

Tags: hive, thrift

I ve hive installed in my ubuntu. Installed PHP5 and apache2 server as well.
Started thrift server using hive --service hiveserver .
Querying hive tables from php file in Command line interface(CLI) giving me expected results.
but from the web browser(`http://localhost:10000/`) i'm not able to invoke hive. 
Tried googling the problem couldn't find it. please help me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hive thrift server just provide a thrift service for hive query but not web service.

I think what you need is HWI (hive web interface). I recommend [this project](https://github.com/anjuke/hwi/). We use it in production environment.

Comment: Tnx for the reply!!!But dont i get to run in web browser if i put all thrift php files in Apache2 var/www and do http://localhost:10000/ from web browser. when i run it in browser i m able to invoke thrift server running but map reduce is not taking place.